# mysql5.7をdeploymentするとエラーがでる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

rubyonrailsでmysql5.7とruby:2.4.2でKubernetesをやってみよう思い

database.ymlを

```
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  database: rails_production
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  username: root
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PORT'] %>
```

に設定し
mysql5.7でdeploymentするとCrashLoopBackOffがでます

`gcloud compute disks create --size 200GB mysql-data`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:5.7
          name: mysql
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: rails
                  key: database_root_password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: mysql-data
            fsType: ext4
```

kubectl describe pod

```
Name:               mysql-55c74486f6-89j7r
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               gke-myrails-default-pool-e9785f10-b4l5/10.140.0.10
Start Time:         Mon, 04 Mar 2019 20:00:46 +0000
Labels:             app=mysql
                    pod-template-hash=1173004292
Annotations:        kubernetes.io/limit-ranger: LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container mysql
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.0.0.15
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/mysql-55c74486f6
Containers:
  mysql:
    Container ID:  docker://488be36176d5f260a09159e69a43ac0825da8c9c6c736574df16dc8d91e32504
    Image:         mysql:5.7
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://mysql@sha256:888d433748dbccc8388a665134b1906f13f599753ef190546903181b7312027d
    Port:          3306/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
       --ignore-db-dir = lost + found
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    127
      Started:      Mon, 04 Mar 2019 20:01:18 +0000
      Finished:     Mon, 04 Mar 2019 20:01:18 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    127
      Started:      Mon, 04 Mar 2019 20:01:04 +0000
      Finished:     Mon, 04 Mar 2019 20:01:04 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  2
    Requests:
      cpu:  100m
    Environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'database_root_password' in secret 'rails'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/mysql from mysql-persistent-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-7xrkt (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  mysql-persistent-storage:
    Type:       GCEPersistentDisk (a Persistent Disk resource in Google Compute Engine)
    PDName:     mysql-data
    FSType:     ext4
    Partition:  0
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-7xrkt:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-7xrkt
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age               From                                             Message
  ----     ------                  ----              ----                                             -------
  Normal   Scheduled               36s               default-scheduler                                Successfully assigned default/mysql-55c74486f6-89j7r to gke-myrails-default-pool-e9785f10-b4l5
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  30s               attachdetach-controller                          AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "mysql-persistent-storage"
  Normal   Pulled                  4s (x3 over 18s)  kubelet, gke-myrails-default-pool-e9785f10-b4l5  Container image "mysql:5.7" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                 4s (x3 over 18s)  kubelet, gke-myrails-default-pool-e9785f10-b4l5  Created container
  Normal   Started                 4s (x3 over 18s)  kubelet, gke-myrails-default-pool-e9785f10-b4l5  Started container
  Warning  BackOff                 4s (x3 over 17s)  kubelet, gke-myrails-default-pool-e9785f10-b4l5  Back-off restarting failed container
```

```
Initializing database
2019-03-04T19:07:34.627201Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-03-04T19:07:34.628690Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2019-03-04T19:07:34.628756Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

となります。誰かこの直し方知っている方いますでしょうか？
教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 私が経験したわけではないのですが[https://qiita.com/shimacpyon/items/50d9a688f88db416d518 ] ではないでしょうか？

Comment: そうするとmysql5.6を使わないとダメってことですか。
ありがとうございます

Comment: いえ、リンクによると`mysqld --initialize-insecure`コマンドで実行すれば良いのでは？

Comment: そのコマンドdeploymentでinit containerで最初かくってことでしょうか？

Comment: ごめんなさい。的外れなコメントでした。「mysql5.7でdeployment」という操作を私は実行したことがありませんでした。どなたか別の方に回答期待します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql5.6に変更しました。
mysql5.7ではまずimageをつくらないとだめみたいです